# PHP How to get the key with the value, FireBase

Tags: php, firebase

So this is my users table structure :

[image]

So what i want is to get the key (0,1,2,3,4,...) with the value of "Nom".

Thank you

Comment: They all have a NOM

Comment: Thats not a normal display for a table with data

Comment: Just do `array_keys($data)` for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the values in an array either from a query or JSON you can loop through them like so:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $person){
    $number = $key;
}
```

Sources: [PHP-Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: $Nombre = $person['Nom']; will get the value of the field Nom. That's not what i am looking for, i i am looking for 1, or 2, 3, 4 ...

Comment: @Fealo I edited my code. It should now return the key of each person.